# Why the difference between the Flash from TV and Movie?

Tags: analysis, dc-extended-universe, arrowverse, the-flash

I was just sitting in my office and wondering over **why there's such difference between the Flash character from TV series and Movies?**

The movies' flash is all kinda kiddish and bit *scared* when big fights come up. He even says to Batman *"I haven't fought with anyone. I just push people a bit"*. While the TV flash, on the other hand, have all the heroic characteristics.

Now I know that the TV series is Flash's own show and the character portrayal is also apt; and also not that the movie's character is bad. But then why the difference between TV and movies? What made the production decide to imply such changes?

Comment: Same reason the 60s TV Batman bears little resemblance to the *Batman v Superman* Batman. They're different interpretations by different production companies.

Comment: Different universes may be.. movie is set in DCEU and tv show is in "Arrowverse"  (whatever that name means though)

Comment: it's the same reason why, even when you have the same play with the exact same script, you can get different interpretations of the character.  every actor and director bring something different to the character.

Answer (score 7):

## It's matter of "tone"

The character names may be the same but their stories and *characterization* will be different.

The same is true of the previous Superman (Reeve, Routh etc. vs. Cavill)  and Batman (many actors/directors) movies.

Zack Snyder explained why they didn't use Grant Gustin...

> "I just don't think it was a good fit,” he told the New York Daily News. "I’m very strict with this universe, and **I just don’t see a version where... that (tone is) not our world.**"
>
> "Even if Grant Gustin is my favorite guy in the world and he’s very good, we made a commitment to the multiverse (idea),” Snyder continued, "so it’s just not a thing that’s possible."
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.mtv.com/news/2797214/grant-gustin-zack-snyder-the-flash-justice-league/)</sup>

The TV Flash & Movie Flash are in different **universes** as far as DC is concerned so they will not be the same although they are, of course, *based* on the same comics character.